# software update is stuck on "less than a minute"

Tags: itunes, macos, install, software-update, airport

since 10.8 was installed on my mac, when i try to update itunes, or airport utility, it always gets stuck on "installing - less than a minute". then i have to shut the computer from the power button since it wont restart or shut down, and then when i try updating again, it gets stuck again. i tried fresh installing,  and it happens on the next update. i tried repairing disk and disk permissions, same.
why does this happen? am i the only one with this problem? is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything interesting in console? Have you tried just installing airport and not itunes and vice versa?

Can you try running software update from terminal:

```
sudo softwareupdate --install --all --verbose
```

Comment: i am trying to update only the airport this time. still stuck. I am trying the terminal now